# GWT PopupPanel incorrect popup position

Tags: html, css, gwt, popup, popuppanel

I'm using GWT PopupPanel to display a popup above a button when user clicks it.

I am setting popup's position and showing it like so:

```
panel.setPopupPosition(leftPos, topPos);
panel.show();
```

However, when I inspect the popup's top value after it shows, I see that it is positions slightly lower than what I assigned it.

The issue may be that setPopupPosition changes the values that are passed in:

```
// Account for the difference between absolute position and the
// body's positioning context.
left -= Document.get().getBodyOffsetLeft();
top -= Document.get().getBodyOffsetTop();
```

How can I make sure the GWT PopupPanel's position is exactly the values I gave it? `setPopupPosition()` seems to really be the only way to set the position, but it does some manipulation (which is unnecessary for my use case) to the positions I pass in.

Comment: You can use direct access to popup's DOM element styles -
 e.g. PopupPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPropertyPx("top", topPos);

Comment: Ahh, see I had tried that and it did not work (popup came up at 0,0) but the key is to set those properties after you call `show()`. This works for me because I do not see the popup "jump" as others mention when setting the position after calling `show()`, but I wonder if there is any way to set the position before calling `show()` without using `setPopupPosition()` ?

Feel free to answer with your suggestion (be sure to mention doing it after calling `show()` and I will accept!

Comment: I've added answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct access to popup's DOM element to adjust PopupPanel position. But it **should be done after calling show() and before making popup visible**. Otherwise, you'll may see some "jump" effects.
Example:

```
PopupPanel popupPanel = new PopupPanel();
...
// this callback will be called after PopupPanel.show(), but before it is shown
popupPanel.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback() {
    @Override
    public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
        Style style = popupPanel.getElement().getStyle();
        style.setLeft(100, Unit.PX);
        style.setTop(100, Unit.PX);
    }
});
```